# .insertBefore() is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a page and upon click button, it opens up a nested field and i want to hide one of the div in the filed upon click but so far my function doesnt work.

my js file

```
$('body').on('click', '#main-applicant-btn', function() {

    event.stopPropagation();
    var prependData = $('.main-applicant').children().first().clone();
    prependData.find("div.checkbox").replaceWith( $( "div.checkbox.hide" ));
    var prependedData = $('.main-applicant').children().last();
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("main-applicant");
    list.insertBefore(prependData, prependedData);
  })
```

my applicant.html.erb file

```
<div class="form-group">
        <%= f.link_to_add "", :applicant_commitments, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pointer add", :id => "main-applicant-btn", :data => {:target => "#main-applicant-#{rand}"} %>
      </label>
    </div>
    <span id="main-applicant-<%= rand %>" class="main-applicant">
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :applicant_commitments do |applicant_commitment| %>
            <%= render "existing_commitment_fields", {:f => applicant_commitment, :instalment => true, :type => 'existing_commitment_applicant'} %>
          <% end %>
        </span>
```

my nested field existing_commitment_fields.html.erb

```
 <div class="form-group monthly-instalment-lender-checkbox">
      <div class="col-sm-3" id="checkbox-existing-fields">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <span>Joint Name</span>
              <%= f.input_field :joint_name, as: :boolean, class: "joint-name-commitment" %>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

So upon click i want to the `main-applicant-btn` and when it displays the nested_fields, i will hide the `div.checkbox` but so far when i try this code, i get error .insertBefore() is not a function.

Anyone has any clues on how to append or force javascript to run code after it has loaded?

Answer (score 8):

[`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) is a Node method.
[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

You've got to iterate through this HTMLCollection or to pick one of the elements inside it to actually touch the nodes and use their method :

`list[0].insertBefore(...,...)`

Also, as mentioned by @nnnnnn, "the `insertBefore()` method isn't expecting jQuery objects as arguments.".
So either you use plain javascript methods like `document.querySelector('')` or you call the target of the jQuery object (`$(...)[0]`)

Comment: Also the `insertBefore()` method isn't expecting jQuery objects as arguments.